# Batch request returning 400 bad request if the file name contains '#' while trying to upload a file to onedrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, batch-request

I have a file named 'File#' which I am trying to createUploadSession to upload it to onedrive.

When I try this API

Url :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{itemId}/File#.txt:/createUploadSession
```

Body :

```
{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
  }
}
```

I get a Success 200 response, but when I try to run the same url with a batch request I get a 400 Bad request even when both the requests are same.

P.S: I have noticed it only happens with the file names which have # in them

I was expecting the batch request to behave in a same way as single independent request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to encode `#` character as `%23`:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "url": "/me/drive/items/{item_id}:/File%23.txt:/createUploadSession",
            "method": "POST",
            "id": "1",
            "body": {
                "item": {
                    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I checked this and it is working.
But I have a question about how to convert # to %23 on C#. Right now I am using Uri.EscapeUriString()

Comment: @VinanthSBharadwaj Try Uri.EscapeDataString("File#.txt") or HttpUtility.UrlEncode("File#.txt")